# Keyboard and Mouse stop working after reboot

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, keyboard, mouse

I was testing my Virtualbox 6.0 on my Ubuntu 18.04 and I tried to boot Mac OS, Windows 7 and Windows 10 at the same time to see how it performs. However my Ubuntu froze and not responding anything, so I had to force it to reboot. After reboot, everything was fine before log into my home, but after that my mouse and keyboard no longer respond to anything, also I notice that seems like the system works, because I do see my Dropbox is logging in and it appears a system crash report, and after 5 mins the screen faded to black, so what can I do?

I tried to fix broken package in the grub but nothing helped.

**Update after 5 mins** 
I tried to log into Ubuntu Wayland and this time it worked, however I have three displays, two connected to the graphic card and one on motherboard. After this incident the display on motherboard no longer is available. However, it is a black screen and only the mouse can be displayed. So I think there was a fundamental error of the system configuration. Do you have any idea how to automatically fix all configuration errors?

Also, if I go back to normal Ubuntu with three display on the keyboard and mouse still don't work